# Astro: Passing JS variable into HTML break the structure

Tags: javascript, html, variables, astrojs

I am trying to create a simple website with Astro but came across this problem. Whenever I try to pass a JS variable **countryCode** into HTML, the structure breaks. The last container is moved into the container before it - https://ibb.co/KjKFbbH

```
---
import MainLayout from "../layouts/MainLayout.astro";

const countryCode = 'DE';

var ibanValid = true;
---

<MainLayout title="IBAN Validator" description="IBAN Validator and Parser">
    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-header">
                <h1>IBAN Validator</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container-body">
                <p class="text-center">
                    To check whether an IBAN is correct, please enter it here:
                </p>
                <input type="text" name="ibanInput" placeholder="..." />
                <input type="button" value="VALIDATE IBAN" />
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <p
                    class:list={[
                        "result",
                        { green: ibanValid },
                    ]}
                >
                    The IBAN is invalid!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-header">
                <h1>Bank Details</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Country Name</td>
                        <td>Germany</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Country Code</td>
                        <td>{countryCode}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-header">
                <h1>Verification</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>IBAN Length</td>
                        <td>true</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ISO 7064 MOD-97-10</td>
                        <td>true</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</MainLayout>
```

If I type the value manually, everything is displayed correctly.
Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to use a client directive `client:load` in the component that holds the code you've shared.